# Can we fetch metrics from pushgateway directlt?

Tags: c#, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I have pushed custom metrics into pushgateway and prometheus **scrape** it every 15sec. I need to fetch metrics before that.  Both pushgateway and prometheus are hosted in my company server so there is no way to change the scraping interval. Is there any way to fetch metrics directly from pushgateway?

Comment: When you say that you need to "fetch metrics before that". You mean in Prometheus or in another application ?

Comment: No.. actually I want to fetch metrcs from pushgateway.

Comment: OK : what you want is to fetch the metrics into an application not related to Prometheus. What's wrong with fetching the push gateway metrics yourself ?

Comment: If you need pushing metrics to Prometheus-like system, then take a look at VictoriaMetrics - it can accept metrics in Prometheus text exposition format - see [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#how-to-import-data-in-prometheus-exposition-format)

Answer (score 0):

You can send a GET request at /metrics endpoint of pushgateway, and it will return all current values.

https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway#query-api